Upgrading to Play 2.9 leads to 503 - upstream connect error or disconnect/reset before headers. reset reason: connection termination for Test Clients
I have been using Play 2.8 successfully without any major issues, however upon upgrading it to 2.9 due to some HTTP connection issues my integration tests that were written in Java have started throwing 503 - upstream connect error or disconnect/reset before headers. reset reason: connection termination even though the same request works fine when I use swagger or a CURL endpoint.
I tried to look into this but despite changing no help. Is there something I should be aware of that has recently changed? Maybe some default timeout or something? For testing, I am using Lombok with Java.
Weirdly enough this happens only with the Java automation test suites and nothing else. Like if I invoke the same API from swagger, postman or any other service it just works. The Java Test Suite is using Java 17 and is also using self signed https certificates. Can anyone help me figure out what maybe going wrong here and what all should I try to fix this?
